# Choose inputs of function with uniform output distribution

Tags: algorithms

**Problem**

I am given a continuous and differentiable* function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers bigger than 1.

Is there a way to choose a set of input vectors such that the corresponding function outputs are uniformly distributed?
Or, can we reduce the problem to some well studied problem for which polynomial time approximation algorithms may exist?

---

**Remarks**

* I'm measuring the distances in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ using euclidean distance, but that's not a strict requirement.

** Similarly, I could also solve my (actual, practical) problem if there was a way to choose a the function inputs s.t. no two of the corresponding outputs have a distance smaller than some constant, predefined $\alpha$.

*** The input domain is constrained, s.t. for any input $x = <x_1, x_2, ..., x_n>$ we have $c_{lower} < x_i < c_{upper} $ for $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, where  $c_{lower} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c_{upper} \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.

Comment: What's your definition of "uniformly distributed"? And is there a particular number of vectors you want to generate?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Karl!
My ultimate goal is to select as many points as possible in the input domain while maintaining a high diversity in the output domain. 
Looking at it from the perspective described in (\*\*), assuming I would want outputs to have a distance to each other of at least $\alpha$, I'd have to find an as large as possible set of inputs while maintaining said constraint. It feels like an exact solution might be awefully hard to find, but might be approximated if I could sample inputs in a way leading to a uniform output distr. (sometimes violating the $\alpha$ constraint)